# Why the html table rows having form element is not showing stripped colours

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code which is expected to produce a stripped table rows.
But what the result iam getting is background colours in all the rows.
When i remove the form tags I am getting table with stripped rows.
How can i get the expected result of stripped table row with form tags.
Thank you for viewing the issue.
Hope this query is clarified.

https://jsfiddle.net/zy1hqLv8/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

   <style type="text/css">
        .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
        .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
         background-color:  rgba(7, 114, 244, 0.52);
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

<h3>Table list</h3><br>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr  >
        <th>Press</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Maintenance</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Done By</th>
        <th>Finished</th>
        <th>Not Finished</th>
        </tr>
    
        <form action="a.php" method="POST">
        <tr >
        <td ><center>AUX</center></td>
        <td ><center>TOOLS</center></td>
        <td ><center>Tools checking and arrangement</center></td>
        <td ><center>2023-09-01</center></td>
        <td> <input  class="form-control" type="number" name="id" value="49" required ></center></td>
        <td> <input   class="form-control" type="text" name="user" maxlength="20"></center></td>
        <td style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="hidd" value="TOOLS"> </td>
        <td ><center><input type="submit" value="Done" name="done"></center></td>
        <td ><center><input  type="submit" value="Not done" name="not"></center></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
                
                
        
        <form action="a.php" method="POST">
        <tr >
        <td ><center>A Press</center></td>
        <td ><center>PRESS-A</center></td>
        <td ><center>Press main inlet airline filter cleaning</center></td>
        <td ><center>2023-09-02</center></td>
        <td> <input  class="form-control" type="number" name="id" value="58" required ></center></td>
        <td> <input   class="form-control" type="text" name="user" maxlength="20"></center></td>
        <td style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="hidd" value="PRESS-A"> </td>
        <td ><center><input type="submit" value="Done" name="done"></center></td>
        <td ><center><input type="submit" value="Not done" name="not"></center></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Run your HTML through a validator first. You may not have a form as a direct child of a table.

Comment: There's two ways to go on this. You can leave your broken HTML since browsers repair it for you in a very clever way , in which case all you need to do is to change `odd` in your CSS to `4n - 1`. Or you can fix the HTML properly by moving each form into one of the table cells of its row, giving each form an `id` and using the `form` attribute on each of the form controls in the same row to point to the form's id.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problem:** You are using `form` as an immediate child in `table` above `tr`, your `table` has no `tbody`, whereas you are using it to target in `css` and you are targeting immediate child in `css` by using `>`.

**Solution:** I have moved `form` inside the `tr` tag and updated `style` to target correctly.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style type="text/css">
    .table-striped tr:nth-child(odd) td,
    .table-striped tr:nth-child(odd) th {
      background-color: rgba(7, 114, 244, 0.52);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Table list</h3><br>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th>Press</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Maintenance</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Done By</th>
        <th>Finished</th>
        <th>Not Finished</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <form action="a.php" method="POST">
          <td>
            <center>AUX</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center>TOOLS</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center>Tools checking and arrangement</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center>2023-09-01</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center><input class="form-control" type="number" name="id" value="49" required></center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center><input class="form-control" type="text" name="user" maxlength="20"></center>
          </td>
          <td style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="hidd" value="TOOLS"> </td>
          <td>
            <center><input type="submit" value="Done" name="done"></center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center><input type="submit" value="Not done" name="not"></center>
          </td>
        </form>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <form action="a.php" method="POST">
          <td>
            <center>A Press</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center>PRESS-A</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center>Press main inlet airline filter cleaning</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center>2023-09-02</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center><input class="form-control" type="number" name="id" value="58" required></center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center><input class="form-control" type="text" name="user" maxlength="20"></center>
          </td>
          <td style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="hidd" value="PRESS-A"> </td>
          <td>
            <center><input type="submit" value="Done" name="done"></center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center><input type="submit" value="Not done" name="not"></center>
          </td>
        </form>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Browsers make an effort to fix broken html. In asker's case, this means removing the `form` element and adding the `tbody` element. In your code, the `form` closing element gets moved up to just behind the `form` opening element (which still breaks the form). You can check this via the browser's developer tools. (Generally, tables are limited to table structure elements until you get into the td/th elements.)

Comment: You are correct, `form` can't be an immediate child of `table`, `tbody` or `tr`. In order to submit the data, OP might need to use some `javascript` to fetch and submit his data.

Comment: JavaScript is not necessary. Instead move the `form` inside one of the cells, give it an id (e.g. `id='my-form'`) and use the `form` attribute to assign all other fields to that form: `form='my-form'`.